# wpf binding text

Tags: wpf, binding

WPF C# VS2008 3.5 I have a few pages(page1.xaml ect.) and I would like to bind text from a textbox to a label on a different page in xaml. I tried using ElementName but the label does not show the text user enters in textbox. I know something is wrong in the Path, but I'm new to wpf so any help would be great. My xaml referenced the x:Name of the textbox, should I reference the page also? thanks in advance

Comment: How are the pages related? Could you post some code?

Comment: on the first page user enters info(perpage.xaml), the last page is a flyer(flpage.xaml) which would contain some of the same info already entered on perpage.xaml. I was trying to save user time by binding textboxes that need same info on both pages.

Comment: thanks to H.B.and Erno for taking time to answer I will work on that idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to create a class that will hold the data and create a single object of that class and bind both pages to it.